# Transitive operation: faithful if and only if stabiliser doesn't have any non-trivial normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

I am working on the following task:

Let $*$ be a transitive group action of $G$ on $Ω$.
Show: $*$ is faithful if and only if for all $\omega \in Ω$ the
stabiliser $G_ω$ doesn´t have any non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$.

My idea:

Let $*$ be faithful. Assume there exists $\omega \in Ω$ and $N$ non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$ so that $N\subset G_{\omega}$  . Then there exists $n\in N, n\neq e$. It follows $n * \omega=\omega $. Because $*$ is transitive, there exists $g\in G$ so that $g * \omega = \alpha, \alpha \in Ω$ . It follows $$n\alpha=n(g\omega)=gg^{-1}n(g\omega)=g(g^{-1}ng)\omega=gmw=gw=\alpha$$ with $m\in N\subset G_{\omega }$.
is this correct?

I am stucked at the other direction...
Now for all $\omega \in Ω$ the
stabiliser $G_ω$ doesn´t have any non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$.
Assume there exists $g\in G, g\neq e$ so that $g \alpha=\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in Ω$.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel of the action is the intersection of all the stabilizers, which can't be nontrivial, because otherwise it would be a nontrivial subgroup of (all) the stabilizers, normal in $G$. So it is trivial and hence the action is faithful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is my proof of the first direction correct?